# Why payments status is pending, but subscription is active

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app on Google Play and have noticed that some transactions are pending (the time frame from when they have been submitted to success have passed more that 7 days). Nevertheless, in such orders it says that the subscription is active.
So there are several questions:

1. Why the transactions are pending, can we as developers check the response from the issuing banks?
2. If transactions are not a success, and the subscription status is active, will there be an attempt to capture the payment when the subscription reactivates?

I did not explore further since I'm waiting to receive information about these questions.